# Pyramid/Pylons: How to check if an uploaded file is complete in a POST request?

Tags: file-upload, pyramid, wsgi, pylons

I'm building a web tool which allows users to upload PDFs to a server using their web browsers. The server is based on Python (Paste + Pyramid).

The problem I have right now is the following: If a user uploads a rather large file (let's say 100 MB) and they cancel the upload before it is completed, my handler code on the server is still called (instead of the request being aborted).

The problem is that the `request.POST['myfile'].file` is incomplete when that happens. This effectively means that the PDF file is corrupted if I simply write it to some place on the server.

When I watch the server's log, it shows a "broken pipe" exception within the Paste server; however I have no idea how to catch that exception and have it prevent my view/handler code from executing and storing the incomplete file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the paster HTTP server does not correctly validate the uploaded form data and simply passes the request down the WSGI pipeline even if the connection (HTTP POST) was closed by the user.

I worked around this issue by simply setting up [NGINX](http://wiki.nginx.org/) to act as a reverse proxy. This also adds some security benefits as it might be better tested than paster.

---

### Update:

My main problem was that I was using `runserver` (the built in web server of manage.py). After some trial and error we ended up using WSGI.

More specifically, [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) and [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) as web server. Static content is served directly by Nginx while dynamic pages are piped through uWSGI and are handled by the Python web app.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing something fancy (like tracking the upload progress, etc), your pylons controller should not be invoked until the entire file has been uploaded.

Comment: Apparently it is. I found a little work-around for this by adding a hidden form field after the file input in the HTML form and check for its existence.